# Second Fragment's onAttach() not called

Tags: android, kotlin

I started an Android project with Basic Activity as template.
This template uses two fragments: First Fragment and Second Fragment, by default.

In onViewCreated() method of the FirstFragment I have the following line:

```
view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_first).setOnClickListener {
   findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment)
}
```

In onViewCreated() method of the SecondFragment I have the following line:

```
view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_second).setOnClickListener {
   findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment)
}
```

I added logging to all the methods in these Fragments but the problem is that only for the FirstFragment is the onAttach() method being called.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: is your second fragment part of the nav controller?

Comment: Yes, I think it is judging by the nav_graph.xml which contains both of these fragments.

Comment: Nvm, I put the name of the TAG I use for logging to be "SecondActivity" instead of "SecondFragment" - that's why I couldn't extract logs from logcat :) Anyways, working now. Thx :)